# How to sort floats in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried `sort`, `Ksort`, `multiSort`, nothing is working and I'm not sure why.I can use `print_r` and see that it is an array but it won't sort just keeps giving errors. I think it is because the values are `floats` but I may be wrong.

Here's a page with the array shown using print_r function:

> http://forcedchange.testdomain.pw/gallery/

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$uploads = wp_upload_dir(); //Path to my gallery uploads folder
if ($dir = opendir($uploads['basedir'].'/gallery-2')) {
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $images[] = $file; 
        }
    }
     closedir($dir);
}

$images = ksort($images);  /* not working */
// echo '<pre>';
// echo print_r($images);
// echo '</pre>';
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<figure><img src="';
    echo $uploads['baseurl'].'/gallery-2/'. $image;
    echo '" alt="" /></li>';
    echo '<figcaption>';
    echo '<p>' .  erq_shortcode() . '</p>';
    echo '</figcaption>';
    echo '</figure>';

}
?>
```

Comment: `ksort` changes the array by reference and returns a boolean (true on success, false on failure), so you shouldn't save it into `$images`. Just do `ksort($images);`.

Comment: the values are not FLOATS - simple strings with image name. sort() should work fine here, as long as $images are indeed the array your print screen shows.

Comment: I forgot to mention that everything works fine in this script until I try to sort it then it gives nothing but errors. I need to be able to sort these images so I can name them in the file folder an order such as 1.png, 2.png, 3.png etc.

Comment: @andrew: sort() *will* work fine here, but it will sort in text order, not in numerical order. For example, sort() will put '10.png' before '2.png'.

Comment: your `$images` array is not an associative array, so using `ksort` makes no sense in this case (because all the indices are already sorted in the order you add them). I doubt what you want is `natsort`, so if you have `1,2, ..., 10, 20` it will be sorted in natural order as what you want, otherwise (using `sort`), it will be something like `1, 10, 2, 20, ...`

Comment: natsort() worked perfect. You can see the final result here: http://forcedchange.testdomain.pw/gallery/  The code creates a basic image gallery using a folder within the wordpress wp-uploads folder.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' hm... true.. haven't thought of that.

Comment: It was the order it was sorting that make me question what I was doing. I tried sort before but the images in the gallery are so random it didnt look like it was changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`natsort($images)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) (don't know which result you want). It should sort the array like:

```
1.png
2.png
...
9.png
10.png
...
20.png
```

Assigning won't work because the sort-funcs return a bool... the sorting is done direct inside the given array.

Comment: Works perfect! I'll have to read up on natsort, I have never heard of it or needed it before this. Thanks so much!

Comment: [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) - here you can see a list of sorting functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
$images=glob("/path/*.{jpg,png,gif}");

ksort($images);

foreach($images as $image)
{
...
... do something with basename($image);
...
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to sort by key.